# Cast a string into Guid in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, casting, guid

I have the Guid "UserID"  , it needs to be filled with Session("UserID") which is a String , but formatted to convert perfectly to a Guid.

If I try this , "Cannot Convert type string into type Guid"

```
       Dim UserID As New Guid()
       If HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID") IsNot Nothing Then
          UserID = HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")
       End If
```

If I try this "Cannot Cast type string into type Guid"

```
       Dim UserID As New Guid()
       If HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID") IsNot Nothing Then
          UserID = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID"), Guid)
       End If
```

This converts the string into Guid perfectly , but it is not accessable outside of the If Statement

```
       If HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID") IsNot Nothing Then
         Dim UserID As new Guid(HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID"))
       End If
```

I can not figure out how to define UserID outside of the If statement , then assign it conditionally

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with this

```
Dim UserID As New Guid()
If HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID") IsNot Nothing Then
    UserID = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID").ToString())
End If
```

Just in case you're confused, take into account that, unless my memory is failing, Guid contructor will generate an "empty" guid. If you want to generate a fresh guid use [`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid)

Comment: could I take out the If statement and use TryParse ? , would that be more efficient?

Comment: @ScottSelby: If make sense according your logic, then you should go for it. I don't know if you need to handle the case where `TryParse` returns false